# Can I access the main page from an Application event?

Tags: events, windows-phone-7

I want to access a property of the main page of my application from inside the `Application_Launching` event. Is this safe to do? Does the page(-object) already exist at this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application lifecycle model goes something like this:

1. App class constructor.
2. `App.InitializePhoneApplication` method (this is where the `PhoneApplicationFrame` that hosts page content is created).
3. `App.Application_Launching`.
4. Page constructor for the startup page.
5. `App.CompleteInitializePhoneApplication` (this is the first time outside of the Page class that you can access the page (from `RootFrame.Content`, though it's visual tree will not yet be created).
6. Page `Loaded` event (at this point the visual tree for the page has been loaded).

What is it that you are trying to achieve? You could set a value in isolated storage and read it in the page, or expose the value as a property in your App class.

Comment: Thanks Derek, this pointed me to the right direction. What I was trying to do is to initialize visual page elements based on saved data. But this code is better placed inside my page. The right spots for me to save and load data seem to be `OnNavigatedFrom` and `OnNavigatedTo`. Although I might also use the `Loaded` event instead of `OnNavigatedTo` (?)